# Using Node-Reds OPC UA Item with changing Item?

Tags: node-red, opc-ua

Sending values per OPC UA works when inputing a msg, msg.payload gets sent as value.

[image: Minimal Example NodeRed]

In this example you can press the top inject node to send true to whatever item is set in OPC UA Item.

---

Leaving the item of OPC UA Item blank is not allowed. Trying to send a different item doesn't work, because the node only tries to send msg.payload per OPC UA, and does not look at msg.topic.

Is there a way to achieve the theorized example of being able to change the Item after deploying, or is there some underlying issue with OPC UA communication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way:

First i checked, what is inside the msg sent by the OPC UA item node, then recreated it with an own implementation:
[image: Node Red Nodes]

_event does not seem to be needed, i added all others:
[image: Messages]

This way, I am able to send my item while being able to change the topic which changes the OPC UA variable that is written.

```
if(msg.topic == "Value")
{
    context.data.payload = msg.payload;
    msg = context.data;    
    return msg;
}    
else if(msg.topic == "Item")    
{
    context.data = {}
    context.data.datatype = "Boolean"
    context.data.browseName = "";
    context.data.topic = msg.payload;
}
```

This is my example implementation that works by first receiving the topic (only Boolean values will be set in OPC UA), then afterwards receiving the value(s).

There probably is a better and more robust implementation, but you can change this for your own use case, whatever works for you. This is just for a proof of concept, so the simplest implementation is best.

Thanks for being interested in this question @whoever upvoted. Maybe someone in the future stumbles across this and it can help them out.